# Reached the max number of texture atlases, can not allocate more for iconView

Tags: swift, google-maps-markers, gmsmapview

My question is exactly the same as ["Reached the max number of texture atlases, can not allocate more" using Google Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43429810/reached-the-max-number-of-texture-atlases-can-not-allocate-more-using-google) but I'm using Gif images so instead of icon I'm working with `iconView` of a marker. Here is the code:

```
let markerGifView = UIImageView(image: UIImage.gifImageWithName("name-of-gif"))
markerGifView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 142)

for i in 0..<latValues.count {
   var marker:  GMSMarker?
   let position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latValues[i], longitude: lonValues[i])
   marker = GMSMarker(position: position)

   marker?.userData = data
   marker?.map = self.mapView
   marker?.iconView = self.markerGifView
}
```

To provide Gif support I've using this: https://gist.github.com/thechaudharysab/b4f9884dcff20c3b8aeb5b4c1fd1756e

Running the app give this error after a few seconds as I scroll through map.

> ((null)) was false: Reached the max number of texture atlases, can not
>   allocate more.